# Post-apocalyptic novel possibly titled Festival

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I read a science fiction novel a long time ago. It was post-apocalyptic and I think the title was (Festival). I can't find any information on it now. Does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: We're going to need a lot more details. More about the plot, when you read it etc. Right now there are either a whole genre of books that exist the only way we can siphon them down is with a possible title. Take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help you

Answer (score 7):

["The Texts of Festival"](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/f/mick-farren/texts-of-festival.htm) by Mick Farren. It’s from 1974.

> In the wilderness of Britain little of civilization remains. Decadence and division have overtaken the huddled people of Festival. And faith in the texts of the old gods - Dhillon, Djeggar and Morrizen - is fading fast.
>
> Beyond the city walls the tribes are massing, united in evil intent. Hill savages fired by ritual superstition to pillage and slaughter. Satanic horse riders inspired by drugs to rape and defile. And crystal-crazed Iggy at the head of them all - a despot in search of territory. A territory like Festival!
> Festival is the 21st century: a community of merchants, bums and drag artists ritually celebrating the runes of the Rock Era - the ancient words of the witch gods: Jagger, Dylan and Morrison.

Around the hills and valleys of southern England roam primitive tribes, trading in dope and beer, surviving on a decaying technology, talking a hybrid of cockney, West Indian and rock slang, feuding and raping, and speeding on 'crystal', while their despotic leader Iggy plans to invade Festival whose tenuous religion is disintegrating as much as the power of its figurehead, the vain, selfish, Lord Valentine.

In this tribal anarchy with its extremes of violence and spiritual insight are the embers of the hassles and ripoffs of today's underground culture, and the joyful, sinister, apocalyptic words of its heroes.

Mick Farren has produced in his first novel the brilliant, macabre adventure of a paradise lost in a hellish eternity.

*The Texts of Festival* may be seen as a bleak forecast of the end of the line for today's alternative society

[image: The book’s cover]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is the answer (Danny3414's looks much more like it) but since I immediately made this connection, maybe it can be useful to someone else.

Charles Stross's [*Singularity Sky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_Sky) is post-Singularity rather than post-apocalyptic and largely features a "Festival":

> In actuality, the planet has been visited by the Festival, a
>   technologically advanced alien or posthuman race that rewards its
>   hosts for "entertaining" them by granting whatever the entertainer
>   wishes, including the Festival's own technology.